# Avoid back window minimizing

Tags: window

I'm creating a 3d model and I have a small window with a photo of my reference. But when I start using the 3d modelling aplication, the small window goes to the back, as it's no longer the active window. Any ideas on how to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method…

Open the picture in [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/index.html), then in Video menu, set to Always on Top